# Post of a specific category - not to be seen in paging previous/next post

Tags: posts, pagination, categories

i have a specific post category, eg. id=x which is not shown in category list.

These posts are password protected and should be visible only to those provided with the link.

However current version still allows see posts from all categories using prev/next posts.

What is the easiest way to ommit some of these category id=x from paging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to exclude the category you don't want to show by adding $excluded_terms to your navigation links. So for example, if the category you don't want showing up is id 4 your link would look like:

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Post', false, '4' );?>
```

Same with `previous_post_link()`.